# Session variables in MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was just wondering if it is normal to use session variables in any kind of sql queries i make in my Php.

this is just a example of what i did.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from bookings where origin = $_session['location']);
```

Can you help me to use session.. Is this the right way to do it? thanks

Comment: Sure, just as long as you change your `$_session` to uppercase; it's a superglobal. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php and that the session was indeed started and quoted in the query. Otherwise, your code will fail, as it stands.

Comment: ^ I believe I "answered" this "completely". You only paying attention to answers below here? Had I known, I'd of put that in as "the" answer.

Comment: Yep your answer was good and clear thanks and i cant mark your comment as the answer because it is just a comment.

Comment: You're welcome. There's nothing stopping you from inviting me to post it as an answer. However, I wouldn't have left it "as is", but with some added information. But that choice is yours in choosing which answer best "answered" your question. IMHO, I believe I have. *Just saying* ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php ,`$_SESSION` Most important object. You can easily handle everywhere in php file.

yes you can use it in your SQL query easily but with Right syntax . e.g. USE `$_SESSION['location']` rather then `$_session['location']` .. 
Now your Sql query would be

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from bookings where origin = $_SESSION['location']);
```

Comment: Thank you, i would have to look up more about sessions

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php  .. read more dear .. it will help you a lot

Answer (score 1):

In any case, you always should think about escaping of data and about existing of value.

```
$location = !empty($_SESSION['location']) ? $_SESSION['location']:'default_location';
$mysqli->real_escape_string($location);
$mysqli->query("select * from bookings where origin = $location");
```